# Amazon RDS MySQL - write throughput limited to 15 MB / s

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

We are duplicating the data inside a rather Amazon RDS MySQL big table, about 2 GB of data.

We are doing that by having batches of 30 entries moved at a time (`INSERT INTO etc SELECT FROM ... LIMIT x OFFSET y`).

The script is working correctly. However, on my local machine with similar anonymized data took about 4 minutes. In RDS it seems to be taking hours.

When investigating seems that RAM and processor are not under stress. However, the write seems to be limited at 15 MB / s.

The volume is a `gp2`, that should have at least 128 MB / s.

What else can cap that speed?

[image: Database Write Throughput]

Comment: The `OFFSET`, if large, may be the slowest part of the query.  What value were you using?  Also, were the indexes the same on the instances?

Comment: RDS uses virtualized storage, which is bound to have higher latency. Multi-AZ RDS has even greater overhead, because it has to sync to remote storage in the other zone. These are physical constraints, and they make RDS have pretty poor performance for writes. If you need high performance, consider using Aurora or else run MySQL on direct-attached storage.

Comment: Frankly, after having done benchmarks on multiple generations of RDS, I wouldn't use that platform for anything more demanding than a private Wordpress blog.